# Gearman - Calculating Statistics

Tags: java, php, metrics, gearman

I'm currently working on a system which uses Gearman for asynchronous data processing.

I can connect to the Gearman server to check the current number of Workers and the size of various queues which is great for working out if processing is backing up etc, but I would also like some stats on throughput for example the Total number of jobs completed/failed in the last 5 minutes/hour/day.

The intention is to store these in the DB and draw some pretty graphs with ExtJS.

There are a couple of other ways I could do this for example getting the workers to ping a collectd instance or counting the number of files that appear, but it seems there should be some simple way to extract this from Gearman directly.

I should probably mention I'm not using persistent queues.

Answer (score 0):

The gearmand currently doesn't have any usage-statistics functions.

I need to do the same for our installation (Perl workers and clients, C dispatcher server) and I'll start counting the number ob jobs processed either in the workers (flush-on-exit) or in memcache.